# Getting object error when getting getElementById value on webpage

Tags: html, vba, web, web-scraping

I am automating web scraping and i'm getting an object error 438 object doesn't support this property or method. in vba when i get to last line of code. If i run it on the internet explorer console, i get the value but i get error in vba. Any help?

```
  Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
  Dim IE As Object

  Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

  If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
    ' Get IE
    Set IE = shellWins.Item(0)
  Else
    ' Create IE
    Exit Sub
  End If    
        
  IE.Navigate "https://mywebpage.com"
  While IE.Busy
      DoEvents
  Wend
  Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
      DoEvents
  Loop
  Dim rtn As String
        
  rtn = IE.getElementById("myID").getAttribute("value") << I get ERROR here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your question in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766491/getting-object-error-when-getting-getelementbyid-value-on-webpage#comment92456418_52766838),

> *is there a way to set an object to an already existing instance of IE ?*

so here's what you can do to grab an already-existing IE browser:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = GetIE("https://mywebpage.com")
```

```
Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim RetVal As Object

    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        sURL = o.document.Location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like "*" & sLocation & "*" Then
            Set RetVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = RetVal

End Function
```

---

Now to the **actual** question. It's impossible to help you precisely without seeing HTML code or the website itself.

However, you can try either of these properties to see if they'd work (Try in the order listed here):

```
Dim rtn As String
rtn = IE.Document.getElementById("myID").Value
```

```
Dim rtn As String
rtn = IE.Document.getElementById("myID").innerText
```

```
Dim rtn As String
rtn = IE.Document.getElementById("myID").outerText
```

Comment: I figured it out but this will work as well...thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method is a property of .document (HTMLDocument) object not the IE object

```
IE.document.getElementById("myID")
```

To create an IE instance:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Comment: How do you suggest getting the IE object method?

Comment: you create the IE instance and loop to set it to the right window if required.

Comment: I don't want to create another instance, I need to use the instance of Internet explorer that is already opened.

Comment: 1) I have answered the question as stated so you should ask a new question for looping open IE windows to find a particular one. Examples exist on SO, so if you are having a problem identifying the right one make an MCVE and post it 2) I have added in the creation of one because it is not visible in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Going to agree with some of the above answers. Get off IE unless its a constraint.

You're not creating an IE object at all. So you're trying to use a non-existent object.

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all: Don't use IE. Firefox and Chrome are much more viable and are actually HTML comformant.

In case this doesn't fix it: Furthermore, if your script runs on startup and is declared before the HTML, it wil try search the current buffer and wont find the object since it hasn't been loaded yet. Try placing the script after the HTML declaration.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood the Code above since I don't actually speak VB ^^'

Comment: How is this an answer, exactly?